# Add array to array without key IDs? - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a big array which looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["Final Fantasy VII"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["rows"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        ["price"]=>
        string(5) "11.69"
        ["price_old"]=>
        string(4) "4.66"
        ["currency"]=>
        string(4) "euro"
        ["portal"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["link"]=>
        string(77) "https://de.gamesplanet.com/game/final-fantasy-vii-download--1001-1?ref=gmkeys"
        ["shop"]=>
        string(4) "9507"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["price"]=>
        string(5) "14.99"
        ["price_old"]=>
        ...
      }
    }
  }

 ["Battlefield 1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rows"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        ["price"]=>
        ...
      }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["price"]=>
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to get only certain parts of this array where the name is matching my searched title. So, I use this code for that:

```
function createACFRepeater($title){
    $repeater = array();

    if(searchForGameXML($title)){

        $count = count($GLOBALS["productsXML"][$title]['rows']);

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
            array_push($repeater, $GLOBALS["productsXML"][$title]['rows'][$i]);
        }

        return $repeater;
    }else{
        return $repeater;
    }
}
```

My problem now is that the the `$repeater` array looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "19.98"
    ["price_old"]=>
    ...
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(4) "7.99"
    ["price_old"]=>
    ...
  }
}
```

There is a numeric key which is pointing to the array `[0] => ...`. But what I want is simply an array in a array without any associative relations...

How can I create an array which looks like this:?

```
array(2) {
      array(6) {
        ["price"]=>
        string(5) "19.98"
        ["price_old"]=>
        ...
      }
      array(6) {
        ["price"]=>
        string(4) "7.99"
        ["price_old"]=>
        ...
      }
    }
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [array definition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) it is impossible. Any array item must have *key* and *value*, documentation for array starts from:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys

Comment: I need this array for a plugin. Watch here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/. And there, the array looks like this: `$value = array(
 array( "sub_field_1" => "Foo1", "sub_field_2" => "Bar1", "acf_fc_layout" => "layout_1_name" ),
 array( "sub_field_x" => "Foo2", "sub_field_y" => "Bar2", "acf_fc_layout" => "layout_2_name" )
);`

But maybe you have an answer to this one also?
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/cannot-update-repeater-field/

Comment: right! but if you write `$value[0]` you receive ` array( "sub_field_1" => "Foo", "sub_field_2" => "Bar" )`. If you omit indexes they are auto-incremented. It does not mean that array does not have indexes at all

Comment: okay, thank you! - I got confused by the documentation of the ACF plugin

Comment: I changed it. It was easier for me to read beacuse of the examples... Do you have a idea to the ACF support link?

Comment: @lubart your link isn't working properly, you added `http://` at the end of the link :)

Comment: I mean this one: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/cannot-update-repeater-field/

Comment: Lubart? - No idea?

Answer (score 1):

You will **always** have numeric keys. As @lubart already said: it's impossible to have an array without keys. Btw., all of the the follwing arrays are completely equal:

```
$array1 = array([0] => array([0] => 'hi', [1] => array([0] => '23.5')));

$array2 = array(array('hi', array('23.5')));

$array3 = [['hi', ['23.5']]];

$array4 = [ [0] => [ [0] => 'hi', [1] => [ [0] => '23.5' ] ] ];
```